# How should I organize hard drive to share a drive if I use both Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

I use Linux for most of the things but I still need Windows sometimes. So, I have Linux Mint 14 and Windows 8 installed (dual-booting) on my computer.

Here's a screenshot of the output of `sudo fdisk -l` command:

[image: 1]

- sda1: The 350 MB partition Windows 8 allocates (I still don't know why.)
- sda2: Windows installation
- sda3: My shared NTFS drive
- sda5: Linux Mint 14 installation
- sda6: Swap area for Linux Mint

Most of my files are in sda3 which I share between the two OSs (kind of like my backup partition). I can access to it from both operating systems. However, sometimes my files gets corrupted.

Example: I recently downloaded Eclipse and extracted it to a folder in sda3 drive in Linux Mint. It was working fine. Then when I switched to Windows, it asked me to repair my drives because there were some errors. I accepted, Windows did some scanning and restarted. When I switched back to Linux Mint, I noticed that Eclipse wasn't working. When I checked, most of the files in Eclipse folder were corrupted. Similar things happen other way around as well. Sometimes I'm not able to see and/or open files in Windows that I created/downloaded in Linux Mint. I'm tired of losing files like this.

I know this can be a hardware issue too. My computer is kind of old. But if it is not, is there a better way to share a drive than what I currently do (a separate NTFS partition for both)?

Answer (score 2):

Use ntfs-3g driver instead of built-in ntfs. Eclipse for linux may include symlinks or files which their names are inadequete for Windows, so Windows wants to corrupt them but that will broke your FS. My suggestion install Eclipse under /opt/eclipse and select workspace as a folder in sda3